# Combine several list comprehension codes

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension, string-concatenation

I got three list comprehensions that do some trimming in a given string. What these are doing is that in a string, it removes words that contain '/', removes certain words in the list called 'remove_set', and combines single consecutive letters into a one big word.

```
regex = re.compile(r'.*/.*')
parent = ' '.join([p for p in parent.split() if not regex.match(p)])

remove_set = {'hello', 'corp', 'world'}
parent = ' '.join([i for i in parent.split() if i not in remove_set])

parent = ' '.join((' ' if x else '').join(y) for x, y in itertools.groupby(parent.split(), lambda x: len(x) > 1))
```

For example:

```
string = "hello C S people in some corp/llc"
```

changes to

```
string = "CS people in some"
```

Can these commands can be written in one beautiful command??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need to `join` just to `split` again in the next line. Also, you can easily combine the first two using `if ... and ...`

Comment: Can't think of a way to improve that last one, except that you might choose other variable names instead of `x` and `y` to make clear what this does, e.g. `length` and `word`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have worked on all of the suggestions, and it works very nice.